# Should I use ajax for updating messages in a chat-client?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am writing a simple chat-client (completely intended for learning purposes). My android phone sends messages to a remote MySQL database, and I am in the process of getting the browser to display any new incoming messages.

My current approach is using javascript: it calls a function every 5 seconds, which in turn calls a php that queries for new messages and sends it back to the browser.

I have no experience in ajax, but I've heard it is good when data has to change in a webpage constantly without having to refresh the page, which fits my situation.

My question is, does this sound like something I should use ajax for?

Comment: The answer your looking for is yes

Comment: yes, unless if you don't mind learning about websockets

Comment: and/or websockets, long-polling, ...

Comment: Thanks guys! Are there any major disadvantages with my current approach though?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ajax is the way to go. However, what you have suggested (checking for messages every 5 seconds) generates a lot of requests and bandwidth. You should look into comet, which is still ajax but uses it in a different way.

Comet essentially is this:The client sends a request to the server. The php file on the server has a loop checking every few seconds for a message. When the server finds a message, it `echo`s the message, but it doesn't close the connection. When another message arrives, it `echo`s it again, but doesn't close the connection. This allows it to only need 1 request instead of hundreds. See http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

Answer (score 0):

I'll advice you to go for either ajax or websockets... if you're going for websocket, learn node.js... it has a lot of cool feature as platform built on Google Javascript V8 engine